# Swift 3 Implement for tap detection on collectionView headers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a UICollectionView with several sections and headers, and I would like to detect a tap on the section headers.

It's working fine for cells thanks to

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

but there is nothing specific to section headers.

I tried to implement a tapGestureRecognizer on the collectionView, which is working, but in that case, the above function is not triggered anymore.

Is there a simple way to implement tap detection on cells as well as on section headers ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You could implement a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the header view itself. Tapping on the header view should trigger the same action than selecting the corresponding cell, right ?

Answer (score 9):

The solution was to attach the tapGestureRecognizer directly on the section and not on the collectionView. And thanks John for the tag tip.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    ...
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "inputStartHeader", for: indexPath) as! GameInputStartHeader
    headerView.tag = indexPath.section

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(tapDetected))
    headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Careful here, you will end up having a lot recognizer every time you dequeue the header. Either you check that a recognizer is present already or remove the recognizer before adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

you can set **blank button** as *headers view* and then set `target` to it.
if you want to perform deferent `action` on **each headerView Click** then you have to set some `tag` as it's `indexPath.section`.